# Want keyboard with track point device between F and G keys, or between H and J

Tags: keyboards, mice

I strongly prefer to use a track point instead of track pad or mouse.

The only nitpick I find is that it is positioned between the G and H keys. I'd prefer it to be between the F and G keys (as a left-hander).

Are there any keyboards, from Lenovo on laptops or others, external keyboards, that place the track point between F and G (for left handed people) or between H and J (for the right handed)?